# How can I give bank card details from my app in appcelerator-titanium to Google Pay and Apple Pay

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, applepay, google-pay

How can I transmit bank card details from my app in appcelerator-titanium to Google Pay and Apple Pay. For example, the card number, card holder and cvv for subsequent card registration in the Google play. How it can be done?

Comment: what do you mean with transmitting the card details? Do you want to start a transaction? There is a Google Pay API you could try to use with Hyperloop: https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/guides/tutorial

Comment: I want to add the card from my application to Gpay. I don't want the user to enter data manually to Gpay. I want this data to be filled in automatically. My application has user's card number, cvv, cardholder name.